# Mirror SQL's LIKE functionality for a PHP array?

Tags: php, ajax, arrays

At the minute I have a page with an AJAX script that searches a database with LIKE '%search term from input box%'.

I need to modify it so that instead of searching the database it searches an array (that has been constructed from two tables - I can't use a JOIN because there's a bit more to it than that).

How do I go about creating a fuzzy search function in PHP that will return all the possible matches from the array?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you want [preg_grep](http://jp.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php)

e.g.

```
$arr = array("tom jones", "tom smith", "bob jones", "jon smith");
$results = preg_grep("/jones/",$arr);
```

`$results` will now contain two elements, `"tom jones"` and `"bob jones"`

Comment: Good solution! But $results = preg_grep("%jones%",$arr); would be a little bit more LIKEly ;)

Answer (score 2):

you could just loop over the array and use strpos to find the matching elements

```
foreach( $arr as $value ) {
   if ( strpos($value, 'searchterm') !== FALSE ) {
      // Match
   }
}
```

You could use a regular expression for more advanced searching, but strpos will be faster if you are just trying to do a simple LIKE '%term%' type search.

Comment: this will not recursively iterate over a multi-dimensional array, however.

Comment: except that would fail for wildcards in the middle e.g. like %dav%d%